# LaTeX, BibTeX and keyword Reference

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

Is there a way of preventing LaTeX class article from printing keyword References. Namely, I would like to get LaTeX to print references from my database processed by BibTeX in the regular fashion but I do not word References to appear on the document.

Comment: It's not BibTeX that prints "References", but LaTeX. Please, state what class you're using.

Comment: I am using article class. Thanks for the prompt respond!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) defines the `thebibliography` environment to typeset the references as a `\section*`. Additionally, it also modifies the headers appropriately to denote a **References* "section". If you want to completely remove this from your output and *just* set the bibliography items, you could use

```
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@startsection}[6]{}% gobble \section*
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo% gobble \@mkboth
  \makeatother
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{references}% References in references.bib
\endgroup
```

The first two command redefinitions (of `\@startsection` and `\@mkboth`) just gobbles their arguments. Grouping keeps the redefinition local so you can still use `\section` (and friends) afterword. A "cleaner" redefinition would be to use

```
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\section}[5]{}% gobble \section*{..} and \@mkboth{..}{..}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{references}% References in references.bib
\endgroup
```

Here's the original definition of `thebibliography`, giving rise to the above redefinitions (I've marked the two commands we want to "remove" via the redefinitions):

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {\section*{\refname}%                                       <--- want to remove this
   \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%  <--- want to remove this
   \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
         \leftmargin\labelwidth
         \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
         \@openbib@code
         \usecounter{enumiv}%
         \let\p@enumiv\@empty
         \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
   \sloppy
   \clubpenalty4000
   \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
   \widowpenalty4000%
   \sfcode`\.\@m}
  {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
   \endlist}
```

The latter redefinition of `\section` assumes the 5 arguments (or tokens) absorbed are

- `#1`: `*`
- `#2`: `\refname` (the braces `{` `}` are dropped by default)
- `#3`: `\@mkboth`
- `#4`: `\MakeUppercase\refname`
- `#5`: `\MakeUppercase\refname`

and is therefore class-specific. You could even go one step further and redefine it (`\section`) to do whatever you want as a replacement. For example

```
\renewcommand{\section}[5]{\par\vspace{20pt}}%
```

would leave a `20pt` vertical space before printing the bibliography entries.

Comment: Why not simply redefine `\section` with five arguments? Look at my comment to another answer

Comment: In that regard, `#1`=`*`, `#2`=`[`, `#3`=??, `#4`=`]` and `#5`=`\refname` (with the braces dropped, of course)? Or what do the 5 arguments represent?

Comment: Werner, thank you so much for this detailed explanation! It is exactly what I need.

Comment: No, you have only to look at `\section*{\refname}\@mkboth{...}{...}` in the definition of `thebibliography`: `#1=*`, `#2={\refname}`, and so on. :) It doesn't matter how `\section` was defined, as TeX uses the *current* definition.

Answer (score 5):

For article you could use

```
\renewcommand\refname{}
```

to suppress the word "References" at the top of the bibliography.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Note that this should still leave a noticeable gap between the end of your text and the start of your bibliography. Also, your headers will be cleared. For example, if you want a previous section's title to continue in the references area.

Comment: A slightly more complicated way would be `\begingroup\renewcommand\section[5]{\par\vspace{3\baselineskip}}\bibliography{mydatabase}\endgroup` which would give you the possibility to choose the spacing between the text and the references.

Comment: @Werner I noticed and I sort of could deal with it but your answer clarify things completely so that I could deal with them properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you should have a look at the `\nocite` command.

Comment: I don't think is what the OP was after.